# How to handle UI based Navigation in Cross Platform Apps?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, j2objc

Assume that you have a cross platform application. The application runs on Android and on iOS. Your shared language across both platforms is Java. Typically you would write your business logic in Java and all you UI specific part in Java (for Android) and Objective-C (for iOS).

Typically when you implement the [MVP pattern](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Presenter) in a cross platform, cross language application you would have the Model and the Presenter in Java and provide a Java interface for your Views which is known to your presenters. This way your shared Java presenters can communicate with whatever view implementation you use on the platform specific part.

Lets assume we want to write a iOS app with a Java part which could be shared later on with the same Android app. Here is a graphical representation of the design:

[image]

On the left side there is the Java part. In Java you write your models, controllers as well as your view interfaces. You make all the wiring using dependency injection. Then the Java code can be translated to Objective-C using [J2objc](https://github.com/google/j2objc).

On the right side you have the Objective-C part. Here your `UIViewController`'s can implement the Java interfaces which where translated into ObjectiveC protocols.

**Problem:**

What I am struggling about is how navigation between views takes place. Assume you are on UIViewControllerA and you tap a button which should bring you to  UIViewControllerB. What would you do?

**Case 1:**

[image]

You report the button tap to the Java ControllerA (1) of UIViewControllerA and the Java ControllerA calls Java ControllerB (2) which is linked to UIViewControllerB (3). Then you have the problem that you do not know from the Java Controller side how to insert the UIViewControllerB in the Objective-C View hierarchy. You cannot handle that from the Java side because you have only access to the View interfaces.

**Case 2:**

[image]

You can make the transition to UIViewControllerB whether it is modal or with a UINavigationController or whatever (1). Then, first you need the correct instance of UIViewControllerB which is bind to the Java ControllerB (2). Otherwise the UIViewControllerB could not interact which the Java ControllerB (2,3). When you have the correct instance you need to tell Java ControllerB that the View (UIViewControllerB) has been revealed.

I am still struggling with this problem of how to handle the navigation between different controllers.

**How can I model the navigation between different Controllers and handle the cross platform View changes appropriately?**

Comment: I think the Spring MVC is a good approach. They have an execution context to store the data for the whole request handling and the next view/action to be executed is mapped by name (String) and decided on runtime. That way, in the Android Java application you could have a Controller delegating to the ObjC the handling of the click request. It returns the name of the next view/action to be executed and the controller reacts properly.

Comment: Could you please be more specific and show some abstract sample code?

Comment: see here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm the StudentController does whatever with the Context (it gets a bean from it with the `@ModelAttribute` but the whole context is just a map of name-value pairs. Then responds with `"result"` knowing nothing about whatever the reference to "result" is. The supposed to be `StudentController` is, in fact, a delegate for the real controller who is running on top of it, deciding what to do next depending on that `"result"` value. Result can be the name of a jsp page, another action...

Comment: @eduyayo SpringMVC is a Server Client Framework for the Web. It has nothing to do with my problem. How should this help me in any way?

Comment: You asked about "a way"... It is a way... I did not say you have to program it embedding a tomcat. It is a way... you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use some kind of slot mechanism. Similar to what other MVP frameworks use.

Definition: A slot is a part of a view where other views can be inserted.

In your presenter you can define as many slots as you want:

```
GenericSlot slot1 = new GenericSlot();
GenericSlot slot2 = new GenericSlot();
GenericSlot slot3 = new GenericSlot();
```

These slots must have a reference in the Presenter's view. You can implement a

```
setInSlot(Object slot, View v);
```

method. If you implement `setInSlot` in a view then the view can decide how it should be included.

Have a look at how slots are implemented [here](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/features/Presenter-Slots.html).

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

Here is how we do it:

- For simple "normal" stuff (like a button that opens the device camera or opens another `Activity`/`UIViewController` without any logic behind the action) - `ActivityA` directly opens `ActivityB`. `ActivityB` is now responsible communicating with the app shared logic layer if needed.
- For anything more complex or logic dependent we're using 2 options:

  1. `ActivityA` calls a method of some `UseCase` which returns an `enum` or `public static final int` and takes some action accordingly -OR-
  2. Said `UseCase` can call a method of a `ScreenHandler` we registered earlier which knows how to open common `Activities` from anywhere in the app with some supplied parameters.

### Long answer:

I'm the lead developer in a company using a java library for the application's models, logic, and business rules which both mobile platforms (Android and iOS) implement using j2objc.

My design principles come directly from Uncle Bob and SOLID, I really dislike the usage of MVP or MVC when designing whole applications complete with inter-component communications because then you start linking each `Activity` with 1 and only 1 `Controller` which sometimes is OK but most of the times you end up with a God Object of a controller that tends to change as much as a `View`. This can lead to serious code smells.

My favorite way (and the one I find cleanest) of handling this is breaking everything up into `UseCases` each of which handles 1  "situation" in the app. Sure you can have a `Controller` that handles several of those `UseCases` but then all it knows is how to delegate to those `UseCases` and nothing more.

Additionally, I don't see a reason of linking every action of an `Activity` to a `Controller` sitting in the logical layer, if this action is a simple "take me to the map screen" or anything of this sort. The role of the `Activity` should be handling the `Views` it holds, and as the only "smart" thing living in the life cycle of the application, I see no reason it can't call the start of the next activity itself.

Furthermore, `Activity/UIViewController` lifecycle is too complex and too different from each other to be handled by the common java lib. It is something I view as a "detail" and not really "business rules", each platform needs to implement and worry about, thus making the code in the java lib more solid and not prone to change.

Again, my goal is to have each component of the app be as SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) as it can be, and this means linking as few things together as possible.

**So an example of simple "normal" stuff:**

(all examples are totally imaginary)

`ActivityAllUsers` displays a list of model object items. Those items came from calling `AllUsersInteractor` - a `UseCase controller`in a back thread (which in turn also handled by the java lib with a dispatch to main thread when the request is completed). The user clicks on one of the items in this list. In this example the `ActivityAllUsers` already has the model object so opening `ActivityUserDetail` is a straightforward call with a bundle (or another mechanism) of this data model object. The new activity, `ActivityUserDetail`, is responsible of creating and using the correct `UseCases` if further actions are needed.

**Example of complex logic call:**

`ActivityUserDetail` has a button titled "Add as a friend" which when clicked calls the callback method `onAddFriendClicked` in the `ActivityUserDetail`:

```java
public void onAddFriendClicked() {  
  AddUserFriendInteractor addUserFriend = new AddUserFriendInteractor();
  int result = addUserFriend.add(this.user);
  switch(result){
    case AddUserFriendInteractor.ADDED:
      start some animation or whatever
      break;
    case AddUserFriendInteractor.REMOVED:
      start some animation2 or whatever
      break;
    case AddUserFriendInteractor.ERROR:
      show a toast to the user
      break;
    case AddUserFriendInteractor.LOGIN_REQUIRED:
      start the log in screen with callback to here again
      break;

  }
}
```

**Example of even more complex call**

A `BroadcastReceiver` on Android or `AppDelegate` on iOS receive a push notification. This is sent to `NotificationHandler` which is in the java lib logical layer. In the `NotificationHandler` constructor which is constructed once in the `App.onCreate()` it takes a `ScreenHandler` `interface` which you implemented in both platforms. This push notification is parsed and the correct method is called in the `ScreenHandler` to open the correct `Activity`.

The bottom line is: keep the `View` as dumb as you can, keep the `Activity` just smart enough to handle its own life cycle and handle its own views, and communicate with its own `controllers` (plural!), and everything else should be written (hopefully test-first ;) ) in the java lib.

Using these methods our app currently runs about 60-70% of its code in the java lib, with the next update should take it to the 70-80% hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

In cross platform development sharing what I call a "core" (the *domain* of your application written in Java), I tend to give to the *UI* ownership of which view to display next.  That makes your application more flexible, adapting to the environment as needed (Using a UINavigationController on iOS, Fragments on Android and a single page with dynamic content on the web interface).

Your `controllers` should not be tied to a view, but instead fulfill a specific role (an accountController for logins/logouts, a recipeController for displaying and editing a recipe, etc).

You would have `interfaces` for your `controllers` instead of your `views`.  Then you could use the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to instantiate your `controllers` on the *domain* side (your Java code), and the `views` on the *UI* side.  The `view factory` has a reference to your *domain*'s `controller factory`, and uses it to give to the requested view some controllers implementing specific interfaces.

[image]

**Example:**
Following a tap on a "login" button, a `homeViewController` asks the *ViewControllerFactory* for a `loginViewController`.  That factory in turn asks the *ControllerFactory* for a controller implementing the `accountHandling` interface.  It then instantiates a new `loginViewController`, gives it the controller it just received, and returns that freshly instantiated view controller to the `homeViewController`.  The `homeViewController` then presents that new view controller to the user.

Since your "core" is environment-agnostic and only contains your *domain* & business logic, it should remain stable and less prone for edits.

You could take a look at [this simplified demo project I made](https://github.com/simondec/simple-routing-example) which illustrates this set-up (minus the interfaces).